# get number of rows in grid ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How do I get the number of rows present in a grid at the form initialization on the init method on Dynamics AX 2012 R3?

Answer (score 2):

After super() you can use SysQuery::countTotal(). You can get query from your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here of SysQuery::CountTotal  http://www.doens.be/2010/03/counting-the-number-of-records-in-a-queryrun/